# R multicycle decompostion

Tags: r

Is there a package that decomposes a series into trend and multiple cycles?
stl is great for one cycle but I would like to find the possibility of other cycles.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at doing a spectral analysis of the series using the fast Fourier transform or a wavelet decomposition. There are plenty of options suggested in the **Decomposition and Filtering** section of the [CRAN Task View on Time Series](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html).

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. What package do you suggest is best for wavelets and what package is best for obtaining a frequency spectrum?